# How to solve this problem when an incoming call arrives?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I want BroadcastReceiver to receive incoming call, so I used

```
<receiver>--android.intent.action.ANSWER --</receiver>
```

in manifest file and my receiver class contains this code

`if(intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_ANSWER)){}`

but my receiver class doesn't receive any incoming call and does not response to me. How to solve this problem?

Thanks All

Answer (score 1):

This action is not a receiver, but an activity one. You can't get receiver to receive the intent. See [here](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=380). Use an activity instead.

See this [example](http://code.google.com/p/teddsdroidtools/source/browse/trunk/teddsdroidtools/src/tss/droidtools/phone/CallAnswerActivity.java).

Comment: @Thanks vladimir,already i used your  code in manifest file,but i did not receive for incoming call

Comment: @How to receive incoming call?

Comment: using activity. Put an intent filter with action listed above on the activity you want to be started when incoming call happens.